# How do I parse one character from Python Pandas String?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame and want to parse the 9th character into a second column.  I'm missing the syntax somewhere though.

```
#develop the data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["vin"], data = ['LHJLC79U58B001633','SZC84294845693987','LFGTCKPA665700387','L8YTCKPV49Y010001',
                                             'LJ4TCBPV27Y010217','LFGTCKPM481006270','LFGTCKPM581004253','LTBPN8J00DC003107',
                                             '1A9LPEER3FC596536','1A9LREAR5FC596814','1A9LKEER2GC596611','1A9L0EAH9C596099',
                                             '22A000018'])

df['manufacturer'] = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','D','D']

def check_digit(df):
    df['check_digit'] = df['vin'][8]
    print(df['checkdigit'])]
```

For some reason, this puts the 8th row VIN in every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code doing this:

```
df['check_digit'] = df['vin'][8]
```

Is only selecting the 8th element in the column 'vin'. Try this instead:

```
for i in range(len(df['vin'])):
    df['check_digit'] = df['vin'][i][8]
```

As a rule of thumb, whenever you are stuck, simply check the type of the variable returned. It solves a lot of small problems.

EDIT: As pointed out by @Georgy in the comment, using a loop wouldn't be pythonic and a more efficient way of solving this would be :

```
df['check_digit'] = df['vin'].str[8]
```

The .str does the trick. For future reference on that, I think you would find [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) helpful.

Comment: Iterating over pandas Series/DataFrames or NumPy arrays is almost never a good idea. Moreover, iterating by index is not pythonic.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
def check_digit(df):
   df['check_digit'] = df['vin'].str[8]
   print(df)
```